# Dynamically change number of thread in pthread

Tags: multithreading, dynamic, parallel-processing, pthreads

Since parallel programs may require different levels of parallelism (e.g., number of threads) at different code blocks, is there a way to dynamically change the number of threads in pthread to always maintain the optimal parallelism during program execution?

We may put unnecessary threads into sleep, but doing so rises issues. First, barriers need to be changed to synchronize a varying number of threads. Second, some parallel programs assign data to individual threads during initialization. Data distribution also needs to be changed with dynamic thread number.

Any ideas or suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best I can come up with is to always try to use pool threads or app-lifetime threads.

Those tasks that must run for the life of the application get started once and are never terminated.

All other tasks are queued to a poll of threads that is sufficiently large that it is unlikely that any task is left queued while there is a core free.